# Evaluation Metric for Imbalanced Classification

Tags: classification, gridsearchcv

I am facing a dataset which has a severe imbalance. I would like to increase the precision and recall of Class 1 (minority class) via GridSearchCV. However, it always turned out that the precision and recall of Class 0 (majority class) is way higher than that of Class 1. The precision and recall of Class 0 is close to 1, whereas the precision and recall of Class 1 is hovering between 0.50 and 0.80.

Is there a cap to the precision and recall of Class 1? How can I increase the precision and recall of Class 1?

Comment: Hi there, why don't you use MCC or Cohen's K to account for the dataset imbalance instead of precision and recall? If you need to use them you can use F1 measure instead.